# Checking the compiled size of JSPs for a Java web application

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jstl, scriptlet

I have run into scenarios where my JSP `service()` method is running beyond permitted 64k footprint. I suppose the obvious answer at this stage would be "Cut it down to smaller scriptlets and control custom tag usage". But I was wondering if I could setup some jobs e.g. via ANT/GRADLE to compile my JSPs beforehand. Will this help to identify which JSP pages will break due to huge scriptlets/tags?

**UPDATE** I do have the `jspc` compile task defined in my ant build file. I am assuming that with `failOnError=false` it's going to do full compilation. But I couldn't find `showSuccess` attribute to set and print out all success msg.

The reason is that my project is quite huge and has about ~1k JSP pages. so i need to find some cheaper solution (or labour option, if you like) to identify these affected JSPs. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

I am using Tomcat 8.0.53 with Ant and JDK 8u125.

KR,

Comment: I've got similar problem, Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Not really - I have precompiled my JSPs as part of the ant/ivy build. But it doesn't report any issue. I was hoping that when no compilation error exists, the 64k footprint error will pop up.

Answer (score 0):

I have temporarily resolved this by

1) Writing a command line java application which will iterate through a list of compiled JSP Class files.
2) Using apache BCEL, I will check each method of the file and compare with 64k size to see which one has gone over.
3) Print them out.

Tomcat classloading is quite unique and requires the tools.jar, ant.jar, and ant-launcher.jar to be there to allow antloader for classloading (hence, ant compiler usage). So I had to come up with a different way of identifying the issue.

Also, it seems that no matter how i configure my ant build, the output never complains about the 64k size until I start the webapp. I have got a separate thread running [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43784641/jsp-compilation-differences-between-ant-build-and-tomcat-runtime)